Tigris package produces error after R update: GDAL Error 1: PROJ: proj_identify: Cannot find proj.db
I recently updated R from 4.3.x to 4.4.1.  I am now getting errors as follows:
mystates <- tigris::states(cb = T)
#> Warning in CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet, : GDAL
#> Error 1: PROJ: proj_identify: Cannot find proj.db

shifted <- tigris::shift_geometry(mystates, geoid_column = "geoid")
#> Warning in CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet, : GDAL
#> Error 1: PROJ: proj_identify: Cannot find proj.db
#> Warning in CPL_crs_from_input(x): GDAL Error 1: PROJ:
#> proj_get_authorities_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): crs not found: is it missing?

trnstates <- sf::st_transform(shifted, crs = "EPSG:4326")
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'shifted' not found

System info:
macOS 14.5
R: 4.4.1
tigris: 2.1
sf: 1.0.16
terra: 1.7.78
stars: 0.6.5
Installed via Homebrew:
gdal 3.9.1
proj 9.4.1

This type of thing can happen if you have multiple installations of GDAL.

It turns out that the issue was due to installing sf from the prebuilt binary hosted by Posit package manager.  When I switched back to using cran.rstudio.com and reinstalled sf, the problems were solved!
